# Extract word with NN tag from tuple in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, pos-tagger

I am trying to extract 0th element in each tuple which have '`NN`' tag. Just want to extract words against the tags. Eg. of each row:

```
train['Tag'] = [('unclear', 'JJ'), ('incomplete', 'JJ'), ('instruction', 'NN'), ('given', 'VBN')]
```

I have tried extracting 1st element in each tuple using where clause

```
train['Tagged2']= [x[0] for x in train['Tag'] if x[1] in ("NN")]
```

Expected results, new column contains each row with words with `NN` tags, here in the example it would be word '`instruction`'

Comment: Could you post the expected output??

Comment: can you tell us when this code fails?

Comment: Can't see why do you ask the question because your code will work as you expected - though a bit weird using `in`.

Comment: Failed because: list index out of range

Comment: @mbajpai then you are asking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Actual problem is raised from your train data. Not the search function.

Comment: @mbajpai May I see your actual traceback?

Answer (score 1):

`==`:

> If the values of two operands are equal, then the condition becomes
>   true.

`in`:

> Evaluates to true if it finds a variable in the specified sequence and
>   false otherwise.

**Hence**:

Use comparison operator `==` instead of `in`:

```
tt = [('unclear', 'JJ'), ('incomplete', 'JJ'), ('instruction', 'NN'), ('given', 'VBN')]

print([t[0] for t in tt if t[1] == 'NN'])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['instruction']
```

**EDIT**:

Since you updated your question:

```
train = {}    # Assuming that you're working with associative arrays i.e. dict in Py

train['Tag'] = [('unclear', 'JJ'), ('incomplete', 'JJ'), ('instruction', 'NN'), ('given', 'VBN')]

print([t[0] for t in train['Tag'] if t[1] == 'NN'])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['instruction']
```

[pyFiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/c4f0d25b-82ef-4cdd-bb23-bdb932a9f990/?i=true)

Comment: Output is: 'instruction'

Comment: @mbajpai `print("".join([t[0] for t in tt if t[1] == 'NN']))` and you will get `instruction`.

Comment: I tried train['tagged2'] = [x[0] for x in train['Tag'] if x[1] == 'NN'] but gives me error "list index out of range"

Comment: @mbajpai your tuples are not all 2 elements then. Check them.

Comment: @mbajpai It works just fine, even added an edit along with a online-test fiddle for you to check!

Comment: probably this isn't even coming from tuples not having 2 elements, as error would have been `tuple index out of range`

Comment: @mbajpai you may accept the answer if it helped! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As you have to create new `pandas` column based on condtion, you can use below code to filter out words with tag `NN`

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Tag'] = [('unclear', 'JJ'), ('incomplete', 'JJ'), ('instruction', 'NN'), ('given', 'VBN')]

# create 2 separate columns with tags and words
df['words'] = [i[0] for i in df['Tag']]
df['tags'] = [i[1] for i in df['Tag']]

# use np.where to find tags with `NN`
df['Tagged2'] = np.where(df['tags']=='NN', df['words'], np.nan)

df.drop(['words','tags'],1,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                Tag      Tagged2                                                                                                     
0      (unclear, JJ)          NaN                                                                                                     
1   (incomplete, JJ)          NaN                                                                                                     
2  (instruction, NN)  instruction                                                                                                     
3       (given, VBN)          NaN
```

Comment: OP tagged the problem with 'pandas' but he did not actually ask for a pandas solution. Introducing 2 third party packages is surely an overkill.

Comment: @knh190 Why do you think using `pandas` and `numpy`(which is actually faster) is overkill to solve `pandas` problem? OP wants to create a new column if you look at his code.

Comment: He didn't mention it at all. He also gave a list, not a pandas dataframe. We yet don't know his actual exception log.

Comment: @knh190 *new column contains each row with words with NN tags,* I think this is clear enough  and you don't initialize list like `train['tag'] = []`

Comment: @DirtyBit thanks ...maybe this question is good example why it is necessary to provide MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

```
train['Tagged3']= train['subclause'].apply(lambda x:' '.join([word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(x)) if pos[0] == 'N']))
```

Comment: Add some explanation to what the code is doing, instead of just pasting the code

Comment: based on the main csv file which contains the subclause column, apply lambda function, tokenize it and note the position if tag starts with N

Comment: add your explanation to your answer and not as a comment